# Currency in webform billing items always dollars

Tags: civicontribute, webform-civicrm, currency

In my installation, under admin/setting/localization, I have enabled multiple currencies. The default is $. The monetary amount display is `%c %a`.

If I create a new contribution page in CiviCRM, I can choose a currency for that page. I've chosen €. Regardless of the setting, it displays $ in the contribution page edit form, but on the preview and live links in CiviCRM, it shows €.

If I create a webform to use that contribution page, the contribution amount widget shows $. Also, in the webform output, the #wf-crm-billing-items table shows the amount in dollars, see below.

I haven't tested, but I expect it will actually charge € from the webform. I also want it to display €.

I have cleared all sort of caches. Is there a setting I am missing or is this a bug ?

[image]

---

PS - interesting little snippet I can do in the console on that page :

```
CRM.formatMoney(9.99)
"$ 9.99"
CRM.formatMoney('init', false, '€1,234.56');
undefined
CRM.formatMoney(9.99)
"€9.99"
```

Comment: .. or is there a way to disable the line items box ?

Answer (score 1):

So that you can actually do

```
   <script>
    jQuery(document).on('ready',function() {
      CRM.formatMoney('init', false, 'RM1,234.56');
      jQuery('tr[data-amount]').each(function(){
         var $this = jQuery(this);
         var amount = $this.data('amount');
         $this.children('td').eq(1).text(CRM.formatMoney(amount)); 
      });
    });
    </script>
```

But, not accepting that as an answer.